# Microsoft Access unable to display image attachment (Runtime Error 2220)

Tags: image, ms-access, runtime-error, attachment

I have a table called "Subsidiary Companies" where I store the names of different subsidiary companies and their corresponding company logo images as an attachment in a table.

I have a form called "invoice" where I use it to generate invoices. Whenever I select a subsidiary from a Combobox, it will change the image attachment box on my form to the one corresponding to the company selected.

After I attach the image to the table it worked. When I closed my entire access program and went back to it, it doesn't work anymore even though I did not change any codes, settings or image path. I got an error instead, "Runtime Error 2220: Microsoft Access can't open the file image.jpeg".

Here is my code to select the attachment image based on the company selected:

```
Me.AttachmentCompanyLogo.DefaultPicture = Me.ComboboxCompanySelection.Column(1)
```

Not sure where it went wrong as I am not very familiar with Access, would appreciate some help, thank you :)

Comment: Loading image to Attachment field should be one operation then use DLookup to display image from Attachment field in Image control. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-access/how-to-display-pictureattachment-field-by-vba/08765d71-30ed-4ea1-91c4-f7b83a040305

Answer (score 0):

based on this statement: " When I closed my entire access program and went back to it, it doesn't work anymore"

- - that behavior would occur if you failed to also include the primary/foreign key cross reference value in the record.  such that when you next go to select it - it can't be found because when you added the image/path it also needed the key value as a cross reference...

this is just a guess of course...
look directly at the table and see if this data is missing...

on a different topic; if you have only a small quantity of images the use of attachments is ok however if there will be a larger quantity then one should not use the attachments feature and instead store the image docs in a separate folder while putting the path to the image doc in a table.